# Check if value exists in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I have data : 1,2,3,4,4,5 & my code like this:

```
<div id="looping" v-for="display in editlistAssesments">
  {{display.test_id}}
</div>
```

My code if in php such as like this

```
$temp_id = array();
foreach($data as $data){
  if(in_array($data ->test_id,$temp_id)){
    echo" 1: no";
    echo" 2: no";
    echo" 3: no";
    echo" 4: yes"; //because he have same value 
    echo" 5: no";
    $temp_id[] = $data ->test_id;
  }
}
```

how I can do that in loop vueJs..??

Comment: But that array in php start empty. I don't quite understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: What does your data look like in your JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to check if value is in array and then render it accordingly?

If so, you need a Vue custom filter. Something like this will do the trick:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: 'body',

    data: {
        editlistAssesments: [1,2,3,4,4,5]
    },

    filters: {
        ifInArray: function (value) {
            return this.editlistAssesments.indexOf(value) > -1 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
        }
    },
});
```

And then use it like this:

```
<div id="looping" v-for="display in editlistAssesments">
    <span v-text="display.test_id | ifInArray"></span>
    <!-- bind Vue value to html element is better practice -->
</div>
```

> Check docs for more information:
>   http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-filter.html

Answer (score 9):

From my point of view, the best way is:

```
<div id="looping" 
     v-for="display in editlistAssesments">
    <span v-if="typeof display.test_id !== 'undefined'">
        {{display.test_id}}
    </span>
</div>
```

Because if you use `v-if="display.test_id"` and the `test_id` value is `0` (*boolean comparation*) you will never see the `display.text_id`.

You can use also this another condition to check if is null or undefined: `display.test_id != null` (*loose equality operator*)