# How To Check In Array Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js, v-for

I have object like this:

```
data() {
    return {
         headings: ['id','remark'],
         rows: [
            {
              id: 1,
              FirstName: 'Jhon',
              LastName: 'Doe',
              remark: 0
           },
           {
              id: 2,
              FirstName: 'Foo',
              LastName: 'Bar',
              remark: 1
           }
         ]
    }}
```

Is there away how do i check if key headings object exist in rows object.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean. Do you mean you want to know if each of the properties specified in your headings array exists on the objects in the rows array?

Comment: @BertEvans Yes Correct .. do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if value exists in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787159/check-if-value-exists-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There's a way

```
function (row) {
   return this.headings.reduce((res, heading) => res &= row.hasOwnProperty(heading), true)
}
```

This method should return true - if the row has the heading.

Comment: @yong-kim, thanks for your suggestion. I was tried your suggestion. On filters i've make function like this :

    filters: inArray: function(row) { return this.headings.reduce((res, heading) => res &= row.hasOwnProperty(heading), true) }


on my own template like this :

    <p v-for="r in rows"><div v-for="r in row" v-if="r | inArray">{{r}}</div>/p>

I want the result like bellow :

    <p><div>Jhon</div><div>Doe</div></p><p><div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div></p>

If keys in rows = id and remarks, they not print on template

Comment: Here's jsfiddle of what I think you are looking for [https://jsfiddle.net/rzsxo7ra/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/rzsxo7ra/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i found solution from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787159/check-if-value-exists-in-vuejs